# How to add privekey.pem and fullchain.pem to a docker container such as elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, logging, backend, kibana

When i build the container of elasticsearch and the compose logs I got  `"WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.29.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/172.29.0.4:54642}"`
And also when I curl to "https://elasticsearch:9200" i got the following `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain` It might be the problem from the SSL certificate?
I have a privekey.pem and fullchain.pem files how to use them in order to solve this issue ?
Noting it is all up but kibana not connected to elasticsearch, and also i tried to disable security but i have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a trial license, Elastic Stack security features require SSL/TLS encryption for the transport networking layer.

This section demonstrates an easy path to get started with SSL/TLS for both HTTPS and transport using the Elasticsearch Docker image. The example uses Docker Compose to manage the containers.

Comment: So what should I do?